# Node.js and CPU cache utilization

Tags: node.js, memory, cpu-cache

I want to understand CPU cache utilisation. For that purpose i wrote a small bit of Node.js code:

```
let testArray = [];
let length = "";
let times = "";

do {
    testArray.push(Math.random());
    if (testArray.length % 1000 === 0) {
        testArray = testArray.slice();
        const start = performance.now();
        action(testArray);
        const stop = performance.now();
        const duration = stop - start;
        length += testArray.length + "," + endOfLine;
        times += duration + "," + endOfLine;
        console.log(`Took: ${duration}, length: ${testArray.length}`);
    }
}
while (testArray.length < 10000000)

function action(a) {
    let sum = 0;

    for (let index = 0; index < 10000; index++) {
        sum += a[index];
    }
}
```

I would expect the duration of the call to the function to be similar to this chart:

[image]

In spite of my expectations the durations are pretty much the same no matter what the size of the array is. I thought that as the array gets bigger it would exceed L1, L2 and L3 caches and I would see it on the graph.

Is my code wrong or am I missing something?

Comment: Your action() function is only going up to 10,000 elements, even if the array is much bigger. Shouldn’t it go over the whole of it, if you want to see some effect growing from size? It would also help if you explained, with precision, not only what you hope to observe, but your understanding of what shall produce such observations.

Comment: Thank You for responding. I have expected that as the array grows the CPU will take more time to read it from RAM as the size exceeds L1, L2 and L3 cache sizes. I intentionally go only through 10k items. If i went through all of them it would obviously take longer for larger arrays.

Comment: Getting data into the cache is done on a per-access basis, never based on the size of the object, of which the CPU has absolute no notion of. In other words, if you read the same amount of data every time (10k), and in the same pattern (sequentially), the behavior of the cache will be pretty much the same.

Comment: (Additionally, as an aside, to have a better chance of observing cache effects I recommend that you use a lower-level language like C, _and verify in assembly that the access pattern the compiler produced is the one you actually want to measure_. With Node, the interpreter could be doing literally anything to access your data.)